# Merge raster data whilst keeping min value and their layer name

Tags: arcpy, raster, numpy, pixel, band

Using numpy and arcpy I can’t figure out a method to do the following:

1. Merge two rasters which have identical cell alignment keeping the minimum value (e.g compare the pixel values and keep minimum)
2. Then, and this is the conundrum for me, add the source name (e.g input array name which had the min value) for each pixel, i.e cell in the array, to a new band of an output raster (that is a raster version of the merged numpy arrays.

Does anyone have any solutions or ideas to this problem? In particular the second section of it. I can’t find a method to carry this out successfully.

Answer (score 2):

One way to tackle this with numpy would be to stack the arrays with `np.dstack()` then use `np.argmin()` to find the *index* of the minimum value in that stack (i.e. which array it came from).  Then you can use that index to also build the final array of minimum values.

This assumes your arrays are the same shape and are single band.

```py
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

arr_a = np.random.randint(0, 100, 100).reshape((10, 10))
arr_b = np.random.randint(0, 100, 100).reshape((10, 10))

stacked = np.dstack((arr_a, arr_b))
idx_min = np.argmin(stacked, axis=-1)
arr_min = np.squeeze(
    np.take_along_axis(
        stacked, idx_min.reshape(idx_min.shape + (1,)), -1))

print('Array A')
print(arr_a)

print('Array B')
print(arr_b)

print('Which array contains the min')
print(idx_min)

print('The minimum value between arrays')
print(arr_min)
```

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html